# D3 force layout: links and nodes --- z-index(?)

Tags: d3.js, z-index, force-layout

D3: problems between nodes and links

I created the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KangMin/MUSKE/4/) to get an idea of what i'm trying to achieve:

[image]

I want nodes to over(?) links...

Please help me. I'm sorry for my English :)

Script looks like this:

```
function myGraph(el) {
this.addNode = function (id) {
    nodes.push({ "id": id });
    update();
}
this.removeNode = function (id) {
    var i = 0;
    var n = findNode(id);
    while (i < links.length) {
        if ((links[i]['source'] == n) || (links[i]['target'] == n)) links.splice(i, 1);
        else i++;
    }
    nodes.splice(findNodeIndex(id), 1);
    update();
}
this.addLink = function (source, target) {
    links.push({ "source": findNode(source), "target": findNode(target) });
    update();
}
var findNode = function (id) {
    for (var i in nodes) { if (nodes[i]["id"] === id) return nodes[i] };
}
var findNodeIndex = function (id) {
    for (var i in nodes) { if (nodes[i]["id"] === id) return i };
}
// set up the D3 svg in the specified element
var w = window.jQuery(el).innerWidth(),
    h = window.jQuery(el).innerHeight();
var svg = this.svg = d3.select(el).append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(.05)
    .distance(100)
    .charge(-120)
    .size([w, h]);
var nodes = force.nodes(),
    links = force.links();
var update = function () {
    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(links, function (d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; })
    link.enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
    link.exit().remove();
    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes, function (d) { return d.id; })
    node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .call(force.drag);
    node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", function (d) { return 30; })
        .style("fill", "#EFEFEF")
    node.append("text")
        .attr("text-anchor", "right")
        .text(function (d) { return d.id; });
    force.on("tick", function () {
        link.attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });
        node.attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
    });
    // Restart the force layout.
    force.start();
}
// Make it all go
update();
}
graph = new myGraph("#graph");
// You can do this from the console as much as you like...
graph.addNode("Cause");
graph.addNode("Effect");
graph.addLink("Cause", "Effect");
graph.addNode("A");
graph.addNode("B");
graph.addLink("A", "B");
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no `z-index` property in SVG; the elements are rendered in the order in which they are specified. This means for you that all the link elements need to be before the node elements in the generated DOM.

The easiest way to achieve this is to have separate `g` elements for links and nodes, with the former first.

```
svg.append("g").attr("class", "links");
svg.append("g").attr("class", "nodes");
```

Then you can append links like this

```
var link = svg.select(".links").selectAll(".link")
         .data(links, function (d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; })
// etc
```

and nodes likewise. Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MUSKE/5/).

Comment: Although this technique worked for me, the problem is when I have to add/remove new nodes/links. When adding a new link for example, the link appears on top of the two nodes it is attached to. Is there a way to always make it appear below the nodes? I tried adding an additional empty `g` but I get errors related to enter(), and I can't understand why `svg.append("g").append("g").attr("class", "nodes");`

Comment: I would keep links and nodes in different `g` elements altogether. Then you can enforce an order within the links and nodes, but relative to each other they will stay in the same order.

Comment: thanks,it work me.i am newbie in svg why it fix this problem?