# D3 z-index of links and nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I got an D3v4 graph in place, where I can dynamical add nodes. My problem is that each added node draws the link above the selected node. Adjusting the z-index seems nothing to change. The `addNode()` creates a new link and new node for now. The node is a mix between hard coded and dynamical yet. Further I push the newly created link to the original graph array and the same for the node.

Any hints how I can fix the problem?

[image: yellow marks the problem]

In following the `addNode()` I am using:

```
function addNode(d) {
    var newid = graph.nodes.length

    var newLink = { source: newid, target: d.id, type: "uses" }
    graph.links.push(newLink)

    graph.nodes.push({
        "id": newid,
        "type": "software",
        "name": "Node",
        "icon": "\ue084",
        "parent": d.id,
        "level": d.level + 1,
        "childs": false,
        "context": [
            {
                "name": d.name
            }
        ],
    })

    link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(graph.links)
        .enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrowhead)')
        .style("display", "block")
        .merge(link)

    linkPaths = svg.selectAll(".linkPath")
        .data(graph.links)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .attrs({
            'class': 'linkPath',
            'fill-opacity': 1,
            'stroke-opacity': 1,
            'id': function (d, i) { return 'linkPath' + i }
        })
        .merge(linkPaths)

    linkLabels = svg.selectAll(".linkLabel")
        .data(graph.links)
        .enter()
        .append('text')
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .attrs({
            'class': 'linkLabel',
            'id': function (d, i) { return 'linkLabel' + i },
            'font-size': 12,
            'fill': 'black'
        })
        .merge(linkLabels)

    linkLabels.append('textPath')
        .attr('xlink:href', function (d, i) { return '#linkPath' + i })
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .attr("startOffset", "50%")
        .text(function (d) { return d.type })
        .merge(linkLabels)

    node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("stroke", "white")
        .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
        .call(d3.drag()
            .on("start", dragStarted)
            .on("drag", dragged)
            .on("end", dragEnded)
        )
        .on("contextmenu", d3.contextMenu(menu))
        .merge(node)

    node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 30)
        .style("fill", initialNodeColor)
        .on("mouseenter", mouseEnter)
        .on("mouseleave", mouseLeave)
        .on("click", click)
        .on("dblclick", dblclick)
        .on("contextmenu", d3.contextMenu(menu))
        .merge(node)

    node.append("text")
        .style("class", "icon")
        .attr("font-family", "FontAwesome")
        .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("font-size", 30)
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .attr("stroke-width", "0px")
        .attr("pointer-events", "none")
        .text(function (d) { return d.icon })
        .on("contextmenu", d3.contextMenu(menu))
        .merge(node)

    simulation.nodes(graph.nodes);
    simulation.force("link").links(graph.links);

    //reheat the simulation
    simulation.alpha(0.3).restart()
}
```

Comment: SVG doesn't use a z-index. Siblings are drawn in the order they are appended, use different `g` parents to hold links, nodes, text, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21304427/7106086).

Comment: Thanks @AndrewReid, but regarding the comments it doesn´t work either as soon as you add/remove nodes. As the initial DOM is already drawn and anything beyond will be drawn on top of it.

It might be not visible straight away but latest during a dragging event. So I thought it would be possible to re-draw all links and nodes, each time a add/remove function was called.

Comment: You'd need to place all your initial circles/text/links into appropriate parent `g` elements, not just the new ones. The alternative is sorting all text/links/circles each time something is added - certainly possible, but usually not preferred.

Comment: I will try that @AndrewReid and let you know.

Comment: @AndrewReid I got it done, of course I need to adjust a bunch of function for now. Thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z-index doesn't work on svg. Svg will draw elements by the order they appear.

So you need to add the nodes after the links, so they are on top.

Because you are adding new nodes/links at a later stage, you can do this:

1. Create the parent containers (first one for links, then one for nodes)

```
var linksContainer = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'linksContainer');
var nodesContainer = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'nodesContainer');
```

2. Now you can add and update your nodes and links to the containers, instead in the svg, and you ensure that the nodes are always on top of the links

Eg: (I hope I didn't miss any svg)

```
function addNode(d) {
    var newid = graph.nodes.length

    var newLink = { source: newid, target: d.id, type: "uses" }
    graph.links.push(newLink)

    graph.nodes.push({
        "id": newid,
        "type": "software",
        "name": "Node",
        "icon": "\ue084",
        "parent": d.id,
        "level": d.level + 1,
        "childs": false,
        "context": [
            {
                "name": d.name
            }
        ],
    })

    link = linksContainer.selectAll(".link")
        .data(graph.links)
        .enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrowhead)')
        .style("display", "block")
        .merge(link)

    linkPaths = linksContainer.selectAll(".linkPath")
        .data(graph.links)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .attrs({
            'class': 'linkPath',
            'fill-opacity': 1,
            'stroke-opacity': 1,
            'id': function (d, i) { return 'linkPath' + i }
        })
        .merge(linkPaths)

    linkLabels = linksContainer.selectAll(".linkLabel")
        .data(graph.links)
        .enter()
        .append('text')
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .attrs({
            'class': 'linkLabel',
            'id': function (d, i) { return 'linkLabel' + i },
            'font-size': 12,
            'fill': 'black'
        })
        .merge(linkLabels)

    linkLabels.append('textPath')
        .attr('xlink:href', function (d, i) { return '#linkPath' + i })
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .attr("startOffset", "50%")
        .text(function (d) { return d.type })
        .merge(linkLabels)

    node = nodesContainer.selectAll(".node")
        .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("stroke", "white")
        .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
        .call(d3.drag()
            .on("start", dragStarted)
            .on("drag", dragged)
            .on("end", dragEnded)
        )
        .on("contextmenu", d3.contextMenu(menu))
        .merge(node)

    node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 30)
        .style("fill", initialNodeColor)
        .on("mouseenter", mouseEnter)
        .on("mouseleave", mouseLeave)
        .on("click", click)
        .on("dblclick", dblclick)
        .on("contextmenu", d3.contextMenu(menu))
        .merge(node)

    node.append("text")
        .style("class", "icon")
        .attr("font-family", "FontAwesome")
        .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("font-size", 30)
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .attr("stroke-width", "0px")
        .attr("pointer-events", "none")
        .text(function (d) { return d.icon })
        .on("contextmenu", d3.contextMenu(menu))
        .merge(node)

    simulation.nodes(graph.nodes);
    simulation.force("link").links(graph.links);

    //reheat the simulation
    simulation.alpha(0.3).restart()
}
```